# Find $n$ so $f\left(z\right)=\begin{cases} \frac{\overline{z}^{n}}{z^{2}} & z\neq0\\ 0 & z=0 \end{cases}$ is continuous but not differentiable at $0$

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, continuity

I am given that:
$$f\left(z\right)=\begin{cases}
\frac{\overline{z}^{n}}{z^{2}} & z\neq0\\
0 & z=0
\end{cases}$$

is continuous at $0$, but not differentiable there and I need to find $n$. What I could figure out is
$$\lim_{z\to0}f\left(z\right)=0\implies\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x^{n}}{x^{2}}=0\implies n>2$$
But I don't see how I can see what is $n$'s exact value. It obviously has something to do with $f$ not being differentiable at $0$ but how can I use that fact?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming the you are looking for integer values of $n$ the answer is $n=3$. If $n >3$ then $\left|\frac {f(z)-f(0)} {z-0}\right|=|z|^{n-3}  \to 0$ which shows that $f$ is differentiable at $0$ with derivative $0$. For $n=3$ $f$ is not differentiable at $0$. [Can you check this?].

Comment: Yes, I can check that. $$f’(0)=\lim\limits_{z\to0}\dfrac{f(z)-f(0)}z=\lim\limits_{z\to0}\dfrac{\overline{z}^3}{z^3}$$ does not exist because $$\lim\limits_{\;\,z\to0\\z=x\in\mathbb R}\dfrac{\overline{z}^3}{z^3}=\lim\limits_{x\to0}\dfrac{x^3}{x^3}=1$$ but $$\lim\limits_{\;\;z\to0\\z=iy\in i\mathbb R}\dfrac{\overline{z}^3}{z^3}=\lim\limits_{y\to0}\dfrac{iy^3}{-iy^3}=-1\ne1\,.$$